Split a multi-value field into multiple records using Microsoft Access SQL
I'm working with a Microsoft Access table that stores its data in the following format:



ID
Document
Revision




8000C001
103A4000X001, 103A4000X002, 103A4000X003
A, B, A


8000C002
103A5000G002/1/01, /02, /03
C, D, B


8000C003
103A6000B001
A



And I'd like to use an SQL Select query to reformat it like the table below:



ID
Document
Revision




8000C001
103A4000X001
A


8000C001
103A4000X002
B


8000C001
103A4000X003
A


8000C002
103A5000G002/1/01
C


8000C002
103A5000G002/1/02
D


8000C002
103A5000G002/1/03
B


8000C003
103A6000B001
A



Documents are divided by a comma, but when documents have the same prefix, subsequent files are abbreviated.
I set up a second table that contains the latest revision of EVERY document, and am currently using an outer join statement to reformat the data.
SELECT 
one.ID
two.Document, 
two.Revision, 
FROM [All Documents] AS one 
RIGHT JOIN [Active Documents] AS two 
ON (one.Document LIKE IIf(InStr(two.Document,"/")<>0, "*" & Left(two.Document,InStr(two.Document,"/")-1) & "*" & Right(two.Document,Len(two.Document)-InStr(two.Document,"/")) & "*", "*" & two.Document & "*")) 
AND (one.Revision LIKE "*" & two.Revision & "*");

This DOES work, but it is very slow. Running the query can take over 20 seconds to finish, so I started writing a second script that uses Unions to format the data instead:
SELECT 
one.ID
one.Document, 
one.Revision
FROM 8110 AS one WHERE one.Document NOT like "*,*"
UNION
SELECT 
one.ID, 
Trim(Left(one.Document, InStr(one.Document, ",") - 1)), 
Left(one.Rev, 1)
FROM 8110 AS one WHERE one.Document LIKE "*,*"
UNION
SELECT 
one.ID, 
IIF(Left(Trim(Mid(one.Document, InStr(one.Document, ",") + 1)), 1) = "/", Left(one.Document, InStrRev(Trim(Left(one.Document,InStr(one.Document,",")-1)), "/")) & Trim(Mid(one.Document, InStr(one.Document, ",") + 3)), Trim(Mid(one.Document, InStr(one.Document, ",") + 1))), 
Trim(Mid(one.Revision, InStr(one.Revision, ",") + 1))
FROM 8110 AS one WHERE one.Document LIKE "*,*";

This is significantly faster than the current query, but it only works on the first two documents. Here's what the output looks like:



ID
Document
Revision




8000C001
103A4000X001
A


8000C001
103A4000X002, 103A4000X003
B, A


8000C002
103A5000G002/1/01
C


8000C002
103A5000G002/1/02, /03
D, B


8000C003
103A6000B001
A



I could solve this by just adding additional unions, but I don't know how many documents a record could contain. Does SQL have some form of recursion? In any other programming language I would just convert the documents into an array using the commas as a delimiter, then add a record for each element.
Also, I understand that the abbreviated files significantly complicate this query. You don't have to account for that in your response; it's my problem to deal with. Here's variants of my queries that don't account for the abbreviated files, and just split them by their commas:
SELECT 
one.ID
two.Document, 
two.Revision, 
FROM [All Documents] AS one 
RIGHT JOIN [Active Documents] AS two 
ON (one.Document LIKE "*" & two.Document & "*")) 
AND (one.Revision LIKE "*" & two.Revision & "*");

SELECT 
one.ID
one.Document, 
one.Revision
FROM 8110 AS one WHERE one.Document NOT like "*,*"
UNION
SELECT 
one.ID, 
Trim(Left(one.Document, InStr(one.Document, ",") - 1)), 
Left(one.Rev, 1)
FROM 8110 AS one WHERE one.Document LIKE "*,*"
UNION
SELECT 
one.ID, 
Trim(Mid(one.Document, InStr(one.Document, ",") + 1)),
Trim(Mid(one.Revision, InStr(one.Revision, ",") + 1))
FROM 8110 AS one WHERE one.Document LIKE "*,*";


No, Access SQL does not handle recursion. Consider changing db structure. At least use a true multi-value field (ugh) but really should be a related dependent table. Otherwise, use VBA to write data to a 'temp' table.

I'd like to use a multi-value field at some point, but whoever set up this database just didn't know that they exist and brute forced everything. Still figuring out the dependencies that I need to change to make this a multi-value.

Are the columns just text as "," separated, or are/is one of the columns a REAL multi-value column? If the two columns REALLY are mutli-value columns, then you can use the .value of that column, and Access will automatic explode the columns for you, and you don't need code.  Unfortantly, it looks like you have 2 multi-value columns, and once again with just some update queries, you can expand the data without code (assuming these ARE real multi-value columns and not just separated columns. However, since you seem to have 2 columns, then VBA code is probably the better solution.

Maybe you can try with a helper table and a VBA function:

Create a new table with sequence numbers 0,1,2,3 as rows (integer column 'Seq'
): tblSeq, with max being maximum no of parts you expect,
Create a VBA function to extract the subpart of the string, given its position:

Public Function GetSubString(Str As String, Seq As Integer) As String
   Dim strRetVal As String, CommaPos As Integer, i As Integer, CommaPosNext As Integer
   strRetVal = ""
   CommaPos = 0
   For i = 1 To Seq
       CommaPos = InStr(CommaPos + 1, Str, ",")
   Next i
   CommaPosNext = InStr(CommaPos + 1, Str, ",")
   GetSubString = Mid(Str, CommaPos + 1, IIf(CommaPosNext = 0, 255, CommaPosNext - CommaPos - 1))
   
End Function

then your query might be like:
SELECT TBL.ID, TBL.Document, TBL.Revision, Seq.Seq, GetSubString(TBL.Revision,Seq.Seq) as Rev
from YourTbl as TBL
     inner join
     tblSeq Seq
on len(TBL.Revision)-len(replace(TBL.Revision,',',''))>=Seq.Seq

Not claiming that it would perform better than any other option, or error free.

Be aware non-equal join SQL cannot be displayed in query Design View. Extracting prefix "103A5000G002/1/" is still an issue to deal with in the VBA as well as parsing the related Revision. Query might perform slowly with large dataset.

My solution was very similar to this. I set up a macro that generates a dependent helper table with all of the multivalues split into individual rows. I also added the prefixes to all of the documents missing them; as you said, the volume of data to be processed caused this to slow down the query.

The difference to your solution is that the helper table can be created upfront, only once; it is not specific to your data, and then the VBA is called from SQL. In other words, single step, just run the query.

You can use VBA and recordset to populate a new table:
Option Explicit

Private rsIN As Recordset
Private rsOUT As Recordset

Sub Fill_New()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rsIN = dbs.OpenRecordset("8110", dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)
    Set rsOUT = dbs.OpenRecordset("NEW8110", , dbAppendOnly)
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Do Until rsIN.EOF
        Dim documents As Variant
        documents = Split(rsIN("Document"), ",")
        If UBound(documents) = 0 Then ' single value in document field '
            AddNew ID:=rsIN("ID"), Document:=rsIN("Document"), revision:=rsIN("Revision")
        Else ' comma seperated values in document field '
            Dim revisions As Variant
            revisions = Split(rsIN("Revision"), ",")
            If InStr(rsIN("Document"), "/") > 0 Then ' / used for revisions '
                AddNew ID:=rsIN("ID"), Document:=Trim(documents(0)), revision:=Trim(revisions(0))
                Dim last_slash_pos As Integer
                last_slash_pos = InStrRev(documents(0), "/")
                Dim base_text As String
                base_text = Left(documents(0), last_slash_pos - 1)
                For i = LBound(documents) + 1 To UBound(documents)
                    AddNew ID:=rsIN("ID"), Document:=base_text & Trim(documents(i)), revision:=Trim(revisions(i))
                Next
            Else ' comma seperated '
                For i = LBound(documents) To UBound(documents)
                    AddNew ID:=rsIN("ID"), Document:=Trim(documents(i)), revision:=Trim(revisions(i))
                Next
            End If
        End If
        rsIN.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsOUT.Close
    Set rsOUT = Nothing
    rsIN.Close
    Set rsIN = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub AddNew(ID As String, Document As String, revision As String)
    rsOUT.AddNew
    rsOUT("ID") = ID
    rsOUT("Document") = Document
    rsOUT("Revision") = revision
    rsOUT.Update
End Sub

